# Creating a folder from QML with /bin/sh -c mkdir

Tags: qml, sh, mkdir

Hi I'm trying to create a folder from QML with a `QProcess` call:

```
qproc.start("/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/x'");
```

It doesn't do anything. Nor does it return any error.
From what I read, this syntax should be correct, is it ?
Might it be permission issue ? How can check this ?

I tried to run the following one in order to know who was the running user of qml script:

```
qproc.start(/bin/sh -c 'whoami &> \"/tmp/mlog.txt\"'");
```

but the output file is not created...

Where should I look at ?

---

Context: this QML script is a user-extension for the [MuseScore](https://www.musescore.org) application running as AppImage. I have no access to the backend. I have to stay in a pure QML solution.

Comment: It [looks like](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#start) the second argument should be a QtStringList i.e. something like `qproc.start("/bin/sh", { "-c", "mkdir -p /tmp/x"})`

Comment: ... your second attempt has some additional issues I think (1) the `&>` redirection is a bashism and (2) the literal quotes

Comment: As I'm in pure QML, a QStringList must be written with `[]`(javascript-style) and not `{}` (which is C#-style). For some reason, in my MuseScore environment `QProcess.start(command, arguments)` returns and error. The key was, as you mentioned, in the quotes (and the `&>` for the second command).

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43105748).
The two expressions must be written like this, with quotes in that precise order.

```
qproc.start("/bin/sh -c \"mkdir -p '/tmp/x/'\"");
```

And

```
qproc.start("/bin/sh -c \"whoami > /home/vboxuser/Documents/log.txt\"");
```